# GWT application not working in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, gwt

I have an application that is using GWT 2.0.4 and running fine on IE8 browser. When opened in IE11, it is giving blank page with error message given below.

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException : (TypeError) : Object doesn’t support property or method ‘attachEvent’
```

The exception was thrown because “attachEvent” is a deprecated function used in older versions of Internet Explorer. IE11 uses “addEventListener” method instead of “attachEvent”.

The user.agent value was set to "ie6" so i changed it to "gecko1_8". After changing user agent it opens the application but the data in table(GWT-ext GridPanel) is getting overlapped over one another, scrollbars are missing and the alignment of menu bar is changed.

It is working fine after enabling the compatibility mode. What is the proper workaround to run my app in IE11 ? Do i need to upgrade GWT and if yes then to which version supports IE11? I don't have to use "X-UA-Compatible=IE8" meta tag....Please help

Comment: hello , I have the same issues . did you solve it  ?

Comment: @marwa: Yes, the issue is solved in IE11. I upgraded gwt to 2.3.0 and added "gecko1_8" as user agent value in *.gwt.xml file. Also changed some css properties for alignment issues in table and scrollbars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As with anything on the Web, you should always try to run the latest version, because everything changes around your application. [2.0.4 is **5 years old** already!](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/downloads/list?can=1&q=2.0.4)

So yes, upgrade to the latest version of GWT (2.7.0 as of today), and when the next version will come (2.8, in a few weeks) try to upgrade as well.

As a workaround, because it works in IE8, you could probably ask IE11 to emulate it using an `X-UA-Compatible` with value `IE=EmulateIE8`. But that's only a temporary workaround, as the next version (Edge, coming in Windows 10 to replace IE) will no longer support `X-UA-Compatible` (except in the *Intranet zone*). See the warning at the top of [the `X-UA-Compatible` doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [this announcement by Mirosoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/developers/articles/week01mar15/upgrading-to-internet-explorer-11-and-windows-10-for-enterprise/). The real solution is to stay up-to-date with GWT versions, just like you stay up-to-date with browser versions.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions....Is it possible to fix this issues in GWT 2.0.4 itself for IE11 as we are not looking for upgradation because it will be a major change....also enforcing compatibility doesn't look good as it will be no longer supported in Edge......Also what user agent value is to be used for IE11 ( as gecko1_8 is causing many UI alignment issues and also key and mouse events aren't working)